# <a> not fully clickable

Tags: html, css

See: http://dals.realsense.co.uk/

In the latest news section (just under the Main Navbar ) - there's a "News Item 1". Any explanations, as to why it is not fully clickable? i.e. only bottom half of the text can be clicked.

Comment: Because your header draws over it. Use firebug or something similar to see.

Comment: Looks like if you set the height to zero on the div art-nav-outer it fixes the problem.

Comment: `Right click -> Inspect element`. It is partly covered by `<div class="art-nav-outer">...</div>`. Please have a look at http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/125997/something-on-my-web-site-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it, regarding such questions.

Comment: Please don't post a link to the site.  Paste the actual code.  Your question will be worthless to future readers as soon as you edit the site.  StackOverflow is as much about visitors for tomorrow as it is about answering your question today.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
div class="art-nav-outer"
```

Is covering your anchor.

You could adjust it's height to match your buttons:

```
.art-nav-outer {
    height:38px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Give your `.news-ticker` a relative position and set the `z-index` to a higher value than the `z-index` of your `.art-bar.art-nav` (which is 100 currently) like:

```
.news-ticker
{
    position: relative;
    z-index: 101;
}
```